# How to add slider with two handles in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, excel-interop

How can one add a slider control object in Excel Interop using Visual Studio 2008?  I don't even see a slider object in the Toolbox.  I added a 'TrackBar', will that allow me to slide across a range of values to assign a value to a parameter?  Is there a better object to use?  Either way, how can I have two handles?  (Have two sliders to give two three ranges for three paramters Ex:  (-20000, -3)(-3, 3)(3, 20000)

UPDATE:  I believe the TrackBar Class is the correct thing to use here but I do not see how to modify one to have 2 thumbs....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.  I found someone who wrote a custom one end ended up using that.  It's a library included in NodeXL, a template add-on to Excel (oh, and it's free!)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, there isn't an object like that in the tool bar, you can use two trackbars. You can create one, here is an excellent video on the subject http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/AnthonyC/Building-Custom-Tools-with-Visual-Studio-2008-Shell.

Comment: Thanks.  I found someone who wrote a custom one and ended up using that.  Unsure how he did it, but it is included in NodeXL, a template add-on to Excel.